# How do I leave static content if property is empty in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a simple angular controller in my app. And I wish to enhance a page containing static content, with angular. This will allow me to have a good, content rich page as fall back for those without JS (who?!) and web crawlers and readers.

So far I have identified a few ways to do this, possibly using custom directives, or by doubling up content in 'ng-bind-template' directive (which is obviously not ideal).

I am fairly new to the world of angular so would like to try and garner the best practice for this scenario.

What is the best approach for this?

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('TestArticle',function($scope, feed){

  $scope.initValue = "This is angular injecting this"
  $scope.activate = function(){
  $scope.eTitle = "Dynamic title";
  $scope.eContent = "Dynamic content";
 };

});
```

**Markup:**

(The problem here is that 'Static content' is replaced by '' if angular initializes)

```
  <div ng-controller="TestArticle">

    <div ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eTitle}}'>Static content</div>

    <div ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eContent}}'>Some more content</div>

    <div ng-cloak>{{initValue}}</div>

    <a href ng-click="activate()" ng-cloak>click to activate</a>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

I should be clear that even though angular is bootstrapping, The aim is to leave the default content intact, and not replace it with dynamic content. That only wants to be achieved once the activate button is clicked.  I have tried the following but it involves doubling up the content which could get bulky if it is a whole article.

```
<div ng-controller="TestArticle">
    <div ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eTitle  || "Static Content"}}'>Static content</div>
    <div ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eContent || "Some more content"}}'>Some more content</div>
    <div ng-cloak>{{initValue}}</div> <a href ng-click="activate()" ng-cloak>click to activate</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple directive to create the html structure that you want.

I propose this to be your new html:

```
<div ng-cloak sk-custom-bind="eTitle">Static content</div>
```

Notice how you don't have to specify the or clause with the static content.

Now you can create a directive that will build the html template for you:

```
app.directive('skCustomBind',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: function(elem, attrs) {
      var templ = "<div ";
      templ += "ng-bind-template='{{";
      templ += attrs.skCustomBind;
      templ += ' || "';
      templ += elem.text();
      templ += '"';
      templ += "}}'></div>";
      return templ;
    },
    replace: true
  };
});
```

And as simple as that you have the functionality that you are looking for without the duplication.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SCSDQsm5w19NRo0HbhW9?p=preview) to see a working sample.

Comment: Bingo! 'Elem' is the piece of the puzzle I am missing. My perfect solution would ideally reuse the defined markup rather than redefine it in the custom directive but I am sure I can achieve this now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @JoseM I have posted a solution below based on your idea, but only replacing content, so no mark-up is in my directive. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that when you define the controller, angular will parse through the html to find all the variables and link them with the corresponding controller items using $scope.

So, when angular initializes, since eTitle and eContent are not having any values (since you initialize them in the function only), which is called on click of the last item(where on your application works fine).

So until you click the button, the static text is replaced by $scope.eTitle and $scope.eContent both of which are undefined. Hence no text inside the tags.

So the solution,
1. Either you initialize the variables inside the controller with the static text, like you did for 'This is angular injecting this'(reason only this came!):

app.controller('TestArticle',function($scope, feed){

```
  $scope.initValue = "This is angular injecting this";
  $scope.eTitle = "Dynamic title";
  $scope.eContent = "Dynamic content";

  $scope.activate = function(){
  $scope.eTitle = "Dynamic title";
  $scope.eContent = "Dynamic content";
 };
```

});

Or you can initialize the variables in the html using ng-init, it will initialize the variable in html only:

```
<div ng-controller="TestArticle">
        <div ng-init="eTitle = 'Static Content'" ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eTitle}}'>Static content</div>
        <div ng-init="eContent = 'Some more content'" ng-cloak ng-bind-template='{{eContent}}'>Some more content</div>
        <div ng-cloak>{{initValue}}</div>

        <a href ng-click="activate()" ng-cloak>click to activate</a>
  </div>
```

The thing is when you start using angular, the html will get kind of hijacked and angular will start using its own variables.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I was beginning to feel ignored ;-) – I have added further comments to my question to clarify. Your first solution doesnt solve the problem as I want to leave the static content, and not replace it with dynamic (on bootstrap)...or at least replace it with the same static content (I am exploring this)

Comment: I have not seen anywhere angularjs leaving static text in ng-bind in my angularjs development life. The way to do that is a directive like the one specified above. Exploring may give you something. Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JoseM for putting me on to right track and helping me find the following solution...

**SOLUTION**

**My Markup:**

NOTE: the custom directive and properties ('cg-dyn' and 'cg-content'). These will not initialise any values when angular bootstraps. And further down you will see how these map from controller scope via an isolated scope.

```
<div ng-controller="TestArticle">

    <div ng-cloak cg-dyn cg-content="eTitle">Static content</div>

    <div ng-cloak cg-dyn cg-content="eContent">Some more content</div>

    <div ng-cloak>{{initValue}}</div>

    <a href ng-click="upDateTitle()" ng-cloak>Update title</a> | <a href ng-click="upDateContent()" ng-cloak>Update content</a>
</div>
```

**My Controller:**

```
app.controller('TestArticle',function($scope, feed){
    $scope.initValue = "This is angular injecting this"
    $scope.upDateTitle = function(){
      $scope.eTitle = "Dynamic title";
    };
    $scope.upDateContent = function(){
      $scope.eContent = "Dynamic Content Lorem ipsum";
    };
});
```

**And finally the magic in My Directive**

```
app.directive('cgDyn',function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope:{
    'content':'=cgContent'
  // this is a two way binding to the property defined in 'cg-content
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    // below is a watcher keyed on a combination content
    scope.$watch('content',function(){
      if(scope.content){
        elem.html(scope.content);
        // and here is the bit, normally plumbed by default, but instead we only replace the html if the value has been set
      }
    });
  },
  controller: 'TestArticle',
  replace: false
};
});
```

Thanks for everyone's help. I am sure there is an even better solution out there so keep the suggestions coming!